# Bootstrap Carousel text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap for one of my projects. Everything works good, but I'm having a problem with the "text" in de default Carousel of Bootstrap. I want it to be in the verticle center of the header and more to the left (next to the left arrow). And I don't know how, tried a few options already. Can you guys/girls help me out?

[Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/UR2us8GARS#)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. First you can set relative position to the wrapper of the carousel and absolute position for the text. Now adjust the top and left properties of the text.
The second way would be using css3 transforms. In this case, you might use translateY() transform for the vertical adjustment and translateX() transform for the horizontal.